# Bootstrap Css Typeahead Not Working ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a problem with typeahead plugin of twitter bootstrap.
Here are my jquery and bootstrap references in the _Layout.cshtml :

```
 <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
            <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/Bootstrap/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            <script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src=  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src ="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js")" type="text/javascript" />
........
```

And Here is My javascript function wich uses the plugin :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#searchAeroRetour").typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            var countries = [];
            map = {};

            // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
            return $.post('/AutoComplete/AeroportLookUp', { query: query }, function (data) {

                // Loop through and push to the array
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    map[country.Nom] = country;
                    countries.push(country.Nom);
                });

                // Process the details
                process(countries);
            });
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            var selectedShortCode = map[item].Nom;

            // Set the text to our selected id
            $("#details").text("Selected : " + selectedShortCode);
            return item;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is the input :

```
.....<td>
      <input type="text" id="searchAeroRetour" name ="searchAeroRetour" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Aeroport" autocomplete="off" />
      </td>.....
```

And here is my Controller called by the javascript function :

```
public ActionResult AeroportLookUp()
    {
        var aeroports = _aeroRepo.GetAll();
        var compAvs = new List<Aeroport>();
        foreach (var aero in aeroports)
        {
            compAvs.Add(new Aeroport() { Nom = aero.Nom, Id = aero.Id });
        }
        return Json(compAvs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

-I have put a Break Point on the method to see if it's called or not and it was not called at all when I type in the textbox. The strange thing is that the same code worked for many inputs in this same page yesterday and today nothing works. Thank you.

**Edit :** screen shot of Console
[image: Console error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the problem :) First of all I am referencing two times the typeahead.js file, once in the bootstrap.min.js that includes himself the typeahead plugin and once with an explicit file that I downloaded. The second problem is the post of the javascript function. I am working with areas, so the best way to call an action is not to hard code the URL using the @Url.Content("~ ....").

Answer (score 0):

In your controller your return type is `ActionResult` while you are returning `Json` value.Try to change your method to

```
public JsonResult AeroportLookUp()
```

Comment: are you getting some error in browser, if not can you post screenshot of the page that is being rendered and source code of that page from browser?

Comment: It can happen if you have same file included twice. Same thing happened for me today.